# add vertical space between equations

Tags: equations

I am using the following code to combine two equations with one number in parentheses but the two equations are very close to each other and using '\vspace{} not working

How can i add a vertical space between these two equations ?

```
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
T_{P} = K_{T}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{4}_{p} \\ 
Q_{P} = K_{Q}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{5}_{p}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can manually add a vertical distance to each line-break. I hope, this is what you want.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{2}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        T_{P} &= K_{T}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{4}_{p} \\[1pt]
        Q_{P} &= K_{Q}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{5}_{p} \\[10pt]
        N_{P} &= K_{N}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{6}_{p} \\[100pt]
        K_{P} &= K_{K}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{7}_{p}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam Glad to hear that. You are welcome.

Comment: Do you know what the default is?

Comment: @theonlygusti that should be `1\jot`

Comment: what does `arara` stands for?

Comment: @alper https://github.com/islandoftex/arara

Answer (score 53):

You can also modify the length `\jot` if you don't want to manually specify the skips for each line. For example

```
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}
```

If you want the change to be localised to that equation, insert the line inside the `equation` environment, as in the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

an equation with more spacing

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\jot}{10pt}
    \begin{aligned}
        T_{P} &= K_{T}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{4}_{p} \\
        Q_{P} &= K_{Q}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{5}_{p} \\
        N_{P} &= K_{N}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{6}_{p} \\
        K_{P} &= K_{K}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{7}_{p}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

and a normal one

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        T_{P} &= K_{T}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{4}_{p} \\
        Q_{P} &= K_{Q}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{5}_{p} \\
        N_{P} &= K_{N}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{6}_{p} \\
        K_{P} &= K_{K}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{7}_{p}
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: @AmeenMohamedBassam You are welcome.

Comment: This isn't working on math stackexchange.

Comment: Not working. I can see no changes in the final output.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to provide a vertical space between two equations could be adding a line which has no numbering using `\nonumber` command, just as below:

```
\begin{flalign}
    T_{P} = K_{T}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{4}_{p} \\ 
    \nonumber \\
    Q_{P} = K_{Q}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{5}_{p} \nonumber
\end{flalign}
```

[image]

I realized you want to set just one number for both equations, in this method you should manually control each line to have numbering or not.

Answer (score -1):

Infinitely simpler method:

```
    \begin{equation}
        \begin{aligned}
            T_{P} &= K_{T}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{4}_{p} \\ \noalign{\vskip1pt}
            Q_{P} &= K_{Q}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{5}_{p} \\ \noalign{\vskip10pt}
            N_{P} &= K_{N}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{6}_{p} \\ \noalign{\vskip100pt}
            K_{P} &= K_{K}. \rho . n^{2}_{p} . D^{7}_{p}
        \end{aligned}
    \end{equation}
```

This uses low-level TeX commands (\noalign and \vskip) and so requires no loading of extraneous packages. You can find this method in the TeXBook.

Comment: The package (`amsmath`) that defines `aligned` also defines the use of the `[...]` modification and the value of `\jot`, so no additional packages are required.  Also, although the suggested per-line modification works in this case, it's not always reliable (i.e., it may not work as expected in other situations that *look* equivalent), and the use of low-level TeX commands isn't recommended in LaTeX.  (But good for reading the TeXbook, to understand the structure on which LaTeX is built.)

Comment: A package that doesn't interoperate with low-level TeX commands should be arguably be avoided, since it is likely introducing other incompatibilities.

Comment: @PhilRegalia your comment really is rather odd as `\jot` is provided by the latex format so no package is needed for that, but `aligned` which you are using does requre loading a package, `amsmath`  so what do you mean by "requires no loading of extraneous packages" ?

Comment: `amsmath` is the standard math support for LaTeX maintained in the same repository as the base format, you can not "arguably avoid" `amsmath` if you are typesetting math in latex.