# Why is there a larger vertical space after the first subequation?

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment, subequations

I am using the subequations environment and observe non-uniform vertical spacing between subequations. Specifically, the space between the first and second equation is larger than the other spaces. Here is the code snippet:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:omegai}
%
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:omega0}
\Omega_0 
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:omega1}
\Omega_1 
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:omega2}
\Omega_2 
\end{equation}
%
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:omega3}
\Omega_3 
\end{equation}
%
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

After doing some debugging I found that the offending command appears to be `fleqn` in the call to `\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,letterpaper]{article}`. If I remove `fleqn` the spacing is uniform. Any ideas how to get uniform vertical spacing and still use `fleqn`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i really hate to say this, but i think it'a a bug in `amsmath`.  (consider it reported.)

the "official dogma" about grouped formulas is that it's better to use one of the
multi-line environments provided by `amsmath` than to separately enter
`\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`, and in fact, by adopting such an environment,
the uneven spacing goes away, at least under some conditions.

here is a possibility that gets rid of the uneven vertical spacing -- but only if
the block of subequations is preceded by some text.  (but that's likely to be true.)

observe that the `gather` environment appears only once, and encompasses all the lines
in the block, while successive lines are separated
by double backslashes.  (the `amsmath` multline environments are meant to be used *only*
with displays that contain more than one line.  if applied to single lines, the spacing
will always be wrong.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent
MMMMMM\hfill MMMMMM%
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:omegai}
%
\begin{gather}
\label{eq:omega0}
\Omega_0 
\\
%
\label{eq:omega1}
\Omega_1 
\\
%
\label{eq:omega2}
\Omega_2 
\\
%
\label{eq:omega3}
\Omega_3 
\end{gather}
%
\end{subequations}
{MMMMMM\hfill MMMMMM\parfillskip=0pt\par}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

if only the display block is present in the file, the uneven spacing between the
first and second lines *may* recur, but it's much less likely.

there are quite a few bugs associated with `fleqn` in `amsmath`; we dutifully test
for them and record them as they are reported.  unfortunately, a full review and
overhaul hasn't yet been scheduled, and i can't predict when it might happen.

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, changing from `equation` environments to either `align` or `gather`, as you suggested. However, instead of getting a larger space between the first and second equations I get uniformly large spacing between all of the equations (unnecessarily large). This doesn't happen with your MWE, but in my actual application it does:

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,fleqn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\noindent
MMMMMM\hfill MMMMMM%
\begin{subequations}
\label{eq:designobjectives}
%
\begin{align}
\label{eq:sy11}
\max \overline{\sigma_{y1}}
\end{align}
%
\begin{align}
\label{eq:s1111}
\overline{S_{1111}} = S_{1111}^{sub}
\end{align}
%
\begin{align}
\label{eq:d}
\min \overline{D}
\end{align}
%
\end{subequations}
{MMMMMM\hfill MMMMMM\parfillskip=0pt\par}

\end{document}

Comment: sorry, not sure how to post latex code in a comment...

Comment: @okj -- don't use multiple `align` environments.  that will *always* insert (unwanted) extra space between lines.  just one `\begin{align}` at the beginning (see how `gather` is used in the example in the answer), with ``\\`` between the lines, and a single `\end{align}` at the end.  you might want to take a look at the documentation -- `texdoc amsmath` on a tex live system.

Comment: `\noindent` even works on its own!

Comment: @davyjones -- if you mean the row of "M"s isn't needed at the beginning, it put that there to show the location of the left margin; neither that "text" nor the `\noindent` are necessary for any other reason.

Comment: @barbarabeeton but i do encounter a large vertical space before `begin{subequations}` and after `begin{block}` in beamer, which cannot be solved by merely adding `\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}}` (from another post). The vertical space seems to be reserved for some words which i did not intend to insert. whereas adding `\noindent` (or `\indent`, except it does not actually indent even if some words are present) solves the problem!

Comment: @davyjones -- aha!  `beamer` is an entirely different kettle of fish.  and `amsmath` was never tested exhaustively in `beamer`, so it's a good thing you have qualified that.  i will put on the "requested" list for `amsmath` to give it a workout with `beamer` and document the results in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

There are `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` around the first equation but there are `\abovedisplayshortskip` and `\belowdisplayshortskip` around other equations. Because these registers have set different values, you see the uneven spacing. TeX internal algorithm uses `\*short*` registers for vertical spacing if there is a horizontal space between the last word of the previous paragraph and the beginning of the equation. Something like this:

```
last word
                equation
```

but it uses no "short" registers in other cases, like this

```
last last lats last word

                equation
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem and did not want to change what I already have much. Here is a workaround by adding an empty row to the top and setting a negative vertical distance for the line-break. It is based on the answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223999/150849 .

```
Some paragraph.
\begin{subequations}\label{eq:exampleNLP}
  \begin{align}
    & \nonumber \\[-30pt]
    & some equations \\
  \end{align}
\end{subequations}
Some other paragraph.
```