# Extra vertical space before display equations in case of `fleqn` option?

Tags: spacing, equations, amsmath

The following MCE points out an extra vertical space before display equations in case of `fleqn` option given at `\documentclass` level.

Do you know what's going on?

```
% Workflow if this file is named `test.tex`:
% pdflatex test
% pdflatex without-fleqn
% pdflatex with-fleqn
% 
\begin{filecontents*}{without-fleqn.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\input{maths}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{with-fleqn.tex}
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\input{maths}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
%
\begin{filecontents*}{maths.tex}
\usepackage[papersize={15cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[step=1cm]{pagegrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Foo :
\[
y=Ce^{-\int a(x)dx}\int b(x)e^{\int a(x)dx}dx
\]
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i think this question/answer is relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235111/579 . unfortunately, the actual reason is not obvious.

Comment: @barbarabeeton isn't a design choice (even without `amsmath`)?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed, in the sense that using `gather` environment instead of `\[...\]` (or `equation`environment) does the trick, but still strange. I guess this is a bug (maybe the same as in this question/answer). Should it be reported?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé -- when i first read your question, i thought the extra space might be there to accommodate a (nonexistent in this case) equation number, but looking further, i found the existing report with a link to the question i already cited.  i've added this report to that record.  but, as before, i can't say when it might get addressed.  sigh.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé did you try without `amsmath`?

Comment: @touhami Yes: same result. Not on your system?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé what i mean is that this may not be related to `amsmath`. `\[` and `\]` are redefined in `flqn.clo` and so do `amsmath.sty`.

Comment: @touhami Indeed. That's the reason I didn't explicitly incriminate `amsmath` ;) But at least it could fix the problem :)

Comment: @touhami it's mostly necessitated by the flush left alignment so would be the same in any implementation.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé it may be an old choice

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that's what i mean by a design choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

[image]

`fleqn` doesn't (and can't really) use the `\abovedisplayshortskip` length, if you set this to `\abovedisplayskip` you get the same space in both cases.

```
\documentclass
%[fleqn]
{article}
\usepackage[papersize={15cm,3cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[step=1cm]{pagegrid}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayshortskip=\abovedisplayskip
Foo :
\[
y=Ce^{-\int a(x)dx}\int b(x)e^{\int a(x)dx}dx
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But why `fleqn` can't really use the `\abovedisplayshortskip` length?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé as your image shows, the short version is used when the equation is small and the last line of the paragraph is short so you can use a smaller vertical space as the last line above "fits" in the space to the left of the equation. fleqn equations never have that space.